# How to integrate external library (p5.js) in middleman 3.4?

Tags: javascript, middleman, p5.js

I have created a sketch with p5.js, which I have placed in my source/javascripts folder.

To work, it requires the p5js libraries (p5.dom.js, p5.js, p5.sound.js).
Where do I place them, and how do I call them?

I have tried to place them directly in the source/javascripts folder where files are called through `//=require_tree` in all.js, but it seems weird as it's a vendor library and I'd rather place it in a separate folder. (And it doesn't work anyway)

I've also tried to place it in a folder I created : source/library, and to call `<script src="/source/libraries/p5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` from my layout.erb file, but it doesn't work either.

Middleman has a vendor folder stylesheets/vendor, but it's for css so probably shouldn't place my js there.

Any idea?

Comment: P5.js does not require those libraries. Those are libraries that can work **on top of** P5.js. If you aren't using the libraries, then you don't need to include them. If you are using those libraries, then you can include them exactly like you're including the main P5.js library. What exactly do you mean when you say "it doesn't work"? Can you be more specific?

Comment: You're right, I probably don't need dom & sound, but I suppose I still need the p5.js library, and I don't know either how to integrate it.

Comment: Ok, went to get some fresh air, and solved my problem. I took away the sound + dom library, and only kept p5.js. Both p5.js and my sketch.js file are now stored in source/javascript, and this works. So all good. Thanks for your help! But is there a way to isolate the p5.js library in another folder, and call it? I'm just thinking if I had many different js libraries, I wouldn't want to keep them with my other js file.

Comment: Can't you just put it in a subdirectory inside `source/javascript`?